# Get count of value change against unique id in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have like below mentioned dataframe (Dput):

```
structure(list(ID = c("TTR-1", "TTR-1", "TTR-2", "TTR-2", "TTR-2", 
"TTR-3", "TTR-4", "TTR-4", "TTR-4", "TTR-5"), Value1 = c(100L, 
400L, 147L, 159L, 165L, 178L, 166L, 150L, 150L, 169L), Value2 = c(15, 
5.05, 13, 13, 13, 7.25, 11, 13, 15, 19), Value3 = c(25L, 25L, 
18L, 32L, 32L, 14L, 45L, 57L, 60L, 22L), Date = c("26/08/2017 06:08:12", 
"26/08/2017 15:45:18", "01/09/2017 12:04:16", "04/09/2017 15:02:47", 
"04/09/2017 18:22:15", "12/09/2017 19:07:17", "15/09/2017 21:19:19", 
"15/09/2017 22:12:47", "15/09/2017 23:15:18", "20/10/2017 09:37:14"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I want to classify it into three different category.

Number of change in Value group by `ID`, considering from beginning date to date by date.

```
ID      Value1  Value2  Value3
TTR-1   1       1       0
TTR-2   2       0       1
TTR-3   0       0       0
TTR-4   1       2       2
TTR-5   0       0       0
```

Number of changes in value group by `Date` (Number of changes made in the unique `ID` on that date).

```
Date        T   U   C     Value1    Value2  Value3
26/08/2017  2   1   1      1        0       1
01/09/2017  1   1   0      0        0       0
04/09/2017  2   0   1      2        0       1
12/09/2017  1   1   0      0        0       0 
15/09/2017  3   1   1      1        2       1
20/10/2017  1   1   0      0        0       0
```

Number of Changes in the Value group by Month.

```
Month   T  U  C     Value1  Value2  Value3
Aug-17  1  1  1     1       0       1
Sep-17  7  3  4     3       2       2
Oct-17  1  1  0     0       0       0
```

Comment: How did you try do it? As says, what code you use?

Comment: @BrunoPinheiro I am using dplyr and tidyr library to separate, filter and group_by but getting some error..:(

Comment: I think in the second output, the Value2 and Value3 values are interchanged

Comment: I also find values for the third output block to be not matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` :

**by ID**

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(d= as.Date(Date,"%d/%m/%Y"),
         m= format.Date(Date,"%m-%d"))

df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize_at(2:4,~sum(diff(.x)!=0))

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   ID    Value1 Value2 Value3
#   <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1 TTR-1      1      1      0
# 2 TTR-2      2      0      1
# 3 TTR-3      0      0      0
# 4 TTR-4      1      2      2
# 5 TTR-5      0      0      0
```

**by date**

```
df %>% group_by(ID,d) %>%
  summarize_at(2:4,~sum(diff(.x)!=0)) %>%
  group_by(d) %>%
  summarize_at(3:5,sum)

# # A tibble: 6 x 4
# d          Value1 Value2 Value3
# <date>      <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1 2017-08-26      1      1      0
# 2 2017-09-01      0      0      0
# 3 2017-09-04      1      0      0
# 4 2017-09-12      0      0      0
# 5 2017-09-15      1      2      2
# 6 2017-10-20      0      0      0
```

**by month**

```
df %>% group_by(ID,m) %>%
  summarize_at(2:4,~sum(diff(.x)!=0)) %>%
  group_by(m) %>%
  summarize_at(3:5,sum)

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   m     Value1 Value2 Value3
#   <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1 08-20      1      1      0
# 2 09-20      3      2      3
# 3 10-20      0      0      0
```

Comment: I assumed that a value changing and going back to original was 2 changes, use `n_distinct` - 1 like akrun did if it's not what you want

Answer (score 1):

We can group by "ID", get the `n_distinct` for 'Value' columns, and substract one

**1) By ID**

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Value")), funs(n_distinct(.) -1))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  ID    Value1 Value2 Value3
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 TTR-1      1      1      0
#2 TTR-2      2      0      1
#3 TTR-3      0      0      0
#4 TTR-4      1      2      2
#5 TTR-5      0      0      0
```

---

**2) By Date**

Similarly, we can do this based on changing the `group_by` variables

```
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Date =as.Date(dmy_hms(Date))) %>%       
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Value")), funs(n_distinct(.)-1)) 
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  Date       Value1 Value2 Value3
#  <date>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 2017-08-26      1      1      0
#2 2017-09-01      0      0      0
#3 2017-09-04      1      0      0
#4 2017-09-12      0      0      0
#5 2017-09-15      1      2      2
#6 2017-10-20      0      0      0
```

---

**3) By Month**

```
library(zoo)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID, Month = as.yearmon(Date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Value")), funs(n_distinct(.)-1)) %>% 
    group_by(Month) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Value")), sum)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Month         Value1 Value2 Value3
#  <S3: yearmon>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 Aug 2017           1      1      0
#2 Sep 2017           3      2      3
#3 Oct 2017           0      0      0
```

Comment: How to add two columns one for total `ID` and second for sum of value change `ID` in `By Date` and `By Month`.

Comment: @VectorJX In the By Date, you can group by both ID and 'Date', then after summarise step, use `group_by(ID) %>% mutate(n = n())`

Comment: @VectorJX  Somelike this `df1 %>% group_by(ID, Date =as.Date(dmy_hms(Date))) %>% summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Value")), funs(n_distinct(.)-1)) %>% group_by(Date, n = n()) %>% summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Value")), sum)`

Comment: The format could be shortened to `"%d/%m/%Y"` since the time is not used.

Comment: @akrun I just want to find out that how many Total, Unique and Changed in values `ID`s were there on particular date and same for month wise as well.

Comment: @VectorJX  Please edit your post with the expected output

Comment: @akrun Edited the Post (i.e T=Total, U=Unique `ID` count and C= Change ID count).

Comment: @VectorJX  The unique ID 'U' and 'C' is not matching with the input example.  Please check why U is 0 for `04/09/2017`, similarly there are other cases.  If there is some typos, then `df1 %>% group_by(Date = as.Date(dmy_hms(Date))) %>% group_by(T = n(), U = n_distinct(ID), C = T- U, add = TRUE) %>% summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Value")), funs(n_distinct(.)-1))`

Comment: @akrun Because `TTR-2` already count as unique on date 2018-09-01, In `U` want to count unique`ID` of particular Day/Months.

Answer (score 0):

Here a playful way to count the unique number of changes by selected variable as defined in the problem description in base R using the OP´s data as data frame DF:

```
DF <- within(DF, {Date <- as.Date(strptime(Date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
                  Month <- format(Date, '%m-%Y')})
cols <- c("Value1", "Value2", "Value3")
namesVector <- c("Date", "ID", "Month")
formulaChar <- paste0('column ~ ', namesVector)

for (i in seq_along(namesVector)){
  temp <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = namesVector[i], all = T),
                 lapply(DF[, cols], 
                        function(column) aggregate(formula = as.formula(formulaChar[i]), 
                                                   data = DF, 
                                                   FUN = function(g) length(unique(g))-1)))
  names(temp) <- c(namesVector[i], cols)
  print(temp)
  assign(paste0("DFby", namesVector[i]), temp)
}

rm(cols, namesVector, formulaChar, i, temp)
```